# Difference between Refresh All Cache , Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage

Tags: magento2, cache, permissions

We are seeing this options from Magento1, but we are not clear what types of cache will be flushed from the system/magento. What needs needs to cleaned or run at what time.

In magento 2 we refresh the cache and also flushed Magento cache, is that mean we have to once again deploy the static content here again.

After Cache clean we are unable to login in Magento admin, after checking the logs file found that var/cache folder don't have the proper write permissions. But before removing cache it has the right permissions.

Can anybody provide insights of handling the Magento cache especially the Magento2 part? As we are seeing the issues after flushing the cache from admin side.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the cache location (like "/tmp/") or service (like Memcache) is shared with other applications. "Flush Magento Cache" removes only those entries that Magento reliably tracks as it's own. "Flush Cache Storage" clears everything but might affect other applications if they're using it.

Normally the location is "var/cache/" in Magento's folder so is not shared after all. It is safe to use either button. Sometimes (rarely) entries are not clearly tagged or Magento loses track of them and only the second button has an effect on them. I tend to use the second button when I'm having difficulty tracking down the cause of a problem.

Comment: Your explanation isn't entirely true - In magento an extension developer or any other developer might use the cache to cache their own data without Magento tags. If you use the right button, magento flushes everything in the cache. If you click on flush magento cache, it flushes only Magento tags.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing are symptoms of a problem rather than the root cause. Your server does not have proper permissions setup for the web user which is causing problems with permissions when Magento tries to create new directories like the cache directory.

Follow the documentation here to assign proper permissions to all the users on your server:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Answer (score 2):

**Refresh All Cache**

> This will flush all the **config**, **layout**, **block_html**, **collections** ,**reflection** ,**db_ddl** ,**eav** ,**config_integration** ,**config_integration_api** ,**full_page** ,**translate** ,**config_webservice** this cache
>   If you want to check the status for the cache then you have to run below command `php bin/magento cache:status`

**Flush Magento Cache**

> By clicking "Flush Magento Cache" removes only those entries that Magento reliably tracks as it's own.

**Flush Cache Storage**

> By clicking "Flush Cache Storage" clears everything but might affect other applications if they're using it.

JFYI,
Sometimes the cache location (like "/tmp/") or service (like Memcache) is shared with other applications. Normally the location is "var/cache/" in Magento's folder so is not shared after all. It is safe to use either button. Sometimes (rarely) entries are not clearly tagged or Magento loses track of them and only the second button has an effect on them. I tend to use the second button when I'm having difficulty tracking down the cause of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Refresh All Cache: This will flush all the **config, layout, block_html, collections ,reflection ,db_ddl ,eav ,config_integration ,config_integration_api ,full_page ,translate ,config_webservice** this cache If you want to check the status for the cache then you have to run below command `php bin/magento cache:status`
- Flush Magento Cache: By clicking **Flush Magento Cache** removes only those entries that Magento reliably tracks as it's own.
- Flush Cache Storage: By clicking **Flush Cache Storage** clears everything but might affect other applications if they're using it.